# search for innerHTML value in a table

Tags: jquery

how can I search in a table for a row with a specifik innerHTML value?

```
<table>
<tr><td>test</td><td>100</td></tr>
<tr><td>test</td><td>200</td></tr>
<tr><td>test</td><td>300</td></tr>
</table>
```

I need the index for the row (tr) where the second td is 200

here the index has to give 1

```
$('table tr'). something??
```

EDIT:

and I also need a version that select the index before a give value is bigger (asc) than 200 (if it exists)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("TABLE TR").each(function() {
    if ($("TD", this).eq(1).html()== "200") {
        // Your logic here

        return false; // break out of .each() loop
    }
});
```

Comment: can you add the possibility to break the "loop" when the value is found?

Comment: and how can I get the index of the row?

Comment: I've turned this into a basic function to make it easier to amend as you need, plus it now returns the index of the row if value is found, -1 if not. http://jsfiddle.net/z5tuD/

Answer (score 1):

var ind = $('table tr:contains(200)').index();